# Determining value to add / subtract scaling

Tags: unity, c#

I have a menu panel.
It appears if the user presses the Enter key, and it disappears if he presses the Enter key again.

When the menu is still hidden, its X scale is set to 0. 
In its normal / expanded state is 0.00175f.
When the menu is shown or hidden, I want to smoothly scale from 0 to 0.00175f or from 0.00175f to 0.

To do that, I have written a coroutine:

```
private IEnumerator pShrinkExpandMenu(bool uShrink)
{
    if (!uShrink)
    {
        Menu.SetActive(true);//the menu should be expanded / enlarged, so we need to make sure it's visible
    }

    float fWidthIfExpanded = 0.00175f;
    float TimeInSecondsToSwitch = 0.3f;

    _TimeElapsedOnShrinkingExpanding += Time.deltaTime;

    while (_TimeElapsedOnShrinkingExpanding < TimeInSecondsToSwitch)
    {
        float fValue;

        if (uShrink)
        {
            fValue = ...
        }
        else
        {
            fValue = ...
        }

        Menu.localScale.X = fValue;

        yield return 0;
    }
    if (uShrink)//if we shrink, and it's completely shrunken, hide it
    {
        Menu.SetActive(false);
    }
}
```

I hope that my coroutine is fine.
One thing that I just don't know is how to determine the value that the X scaling should be changed during one loop.

I have no idea how to calculate fValue.

Could anybody explain that to me, please?

Comment: That's a very strange scale value, and suggests there might be something funny going on with how the menu itself is set up. I'd recommend finding a way to author your content so the objects you're manipulating are typically in 1.0f scale, or at least uniform on all axes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three simple changes:

1. Compute a start & target scale depending on whether you're shrinking or growing. I just do it with a ternary operator: `float targetScale = uShrink ? 0f : fWidthIfExpanded;`
2. You can replace your `while` loop with a `for` loop, which includes your time incrementing logic built-in.
3. Compute your intermediate value with a `Lerp` (linear interpolation) between your start and your end, proportional to how close `elapsed` gets to your duration.

Something like this:

```
private IEnumerator pShrinkExpandMenu(bool uShrink)
{
    if (!uShrink)
    {
        Menu.SetActive(true);//the menu should be expanded / enlarged, so we need to make sure it's visible
    }

    float fWidthIfExpanded = 0.00175f;
    float TimeInSecondsToSwitch = 0.3f;

    float startScale = Menu.transform.localScale.x;
    float targetScale = uShrink ? 0f : fWidthIfExpanded;

    for (float elapsed = 0f; elapsed < TimeInSecondsToSwitch; elapsed += Time.deltaTime)
    {
        float blend = elapsed/TimeInSecondsToSwitch;

        // You can apply some non-linear mapping to blend here for an easing effect.
        // eg. blend *= blend will give you a quadratic ease-out

        var scale = Menu.localScale;
        scale.x = Mathf.Lerp(startScale, targetScale, blend);
        Menu.localScale = scale;

        yield return null;
    }

    if (uShrink)//if we shrink, and it's completely shrunken, hide it
    {
        Menu.SetActive(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you, also for the great explanation!

Comment: I wanted to make it so the the menu starts growing / shrinking from the left side. Currently it shrinks / grows from the middle. Can you perhaps show me your idea of how to ideally (re)position it so that it looks like its unfolding from the left and also shrinking towards the left? I hope I could explain it well?

Comment: Don't make your code do that - do it with your scene setup. Set the pivot or anchors of the object so they're located at the left side, so you don't need to micromanage things like this in code.